# TWRP breaks data partition (couldn't boot into ubuntu touch)

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch

I followed this guide: https://forums.ubports.com/topic/4964/fairphone-3-fp3
downloaded stable GITLAB CI

I flashed boot.img and system.img, also used TWRP, stuck at android bootloader start screen
flashed boot.img and system.img again, stuck at start again

I also tried an older one but - nothing
Now I need a step-by-step guide from YOU and much help

thank you for help!!!

The Problem was that twrp broke the data partition and the recovery repaired it so when ubuntu-touch doesn't boot, you have to try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you start recovery one time!!!!
Just wait a bit and when screen color changes you win

Answer (score 1):

The port of Ubuntu Touch for the Fairphone 3 is not yet daily driver ready, it's still pretty much under developement, as you can see on the [UBports forum page for the Halium 10 based port](https://forums.ubports.com/topic/5939/fairphone-3-3-fp3-fp3-port-halium-10), some pretty relevant stuff like the ability to play media (video and audio) is still not working. The page also has instructions for flashing, and people discussing issue they had while doing it.